# How to structure language YAML files for PyI18N translation

Tags: python-3.x, internationalization

I've been trying to follow the steps shown [here](https://github.com/sectasy0/pyi18n). Honestly, they are not 100% perfect and I had to tweak some things here and there, but this is what my final script is.

```
from pyi18n import PyI18n
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    available_locales: tuple[str] = ('en', 'pl')

    user_locale: str = input('Enter your locale: ')
    if user_locale.lower() not in available_locales:
        print('Locale not supported, please select another one')
        sys.exit(1)

    i18n: PyI18n = PyI18n(user_locale)
    _ = i18n.gettext

    print(_(user_locale, 'messages.welcome'))
    print("============================")
    print(_(user_locale, 'labels.products'))
```

Please note that I passed a single string as the argument to `PyI18n`, as passing a tuple of strings as shown in the docs, gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharthsamant/Documents/scripts/localisation-poc/store.py", line 13, in <module>
    i18n: PyI18n = PyI18n(available_locales)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyi18n/pyi18n.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.__pyi18n_init()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyi18n/pyi18n.py", line 80, in __pyi18n_init
    self._loaded_translations: dict = self.loader.load(
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyi18n/loaders.py", line 200, in load
    return super().load(locales, yaml)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyi18n/loaders.py", line 75, in load
    loaded[locale] = self.__load_file(file_path,
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyi18n/loaders.py", line 100, in __load_file
    return ser_mod.load(_f, **load_params)[locale]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Having changed that tuple of strings to a single string, this is my directory structure

```
.
├── locales
│   ├── en.yml
│   └── pl.yml
└── store.py
```

But when I run `store.py` passing `en` as the language, I get this

```
Enter your locale: en
missing translation for: en.messages.welcome
============================
missing translation for: en.labels.products
```

And this is my `en.yml`

```
en:
    labels:
        products: Products
    messages:
        welcome: Welcome
```

It seems that the YAML structure/syntax is wrong, but I can't find any documentation online for this. Even the sample YAML in the Github repo ([link](https://github.com/sectasy0/pyi18n/blob/master/tests/fixtures/locales/en.yml)) have the same format.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this topic by accident, did you deal with this problem? I am the author of this library. The `PyI18n` class should be created with the `available_locales` parameter, not the input of the user (current locale). That's why you're getting this error because `PyI18n` init function expects a tuple of available locales, so your code should be:

```py
available_locales: tuple[str] = ('en', 'pl')

i18n: PyI18n = PyI18n(available_locales)
_ = i18n.gettext
```